# Selenium get element by XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I have following code where i want to select value for dropdown:

```
   <div class="prod-value col-xs-6 col-sm-8">
    <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-style="btn-default btn-sm" data-width="98%" data-size="6" onchange="location=options[selectedIndex].value;" style="display: none;"><option value="/design-your-engagement-ring/choose-a-setting/10k-rose-gold-round-halo-engagement-ring/50277-E-10KR">10K Rose Gold</option>
        <option value="aa">10K White Gold</option>
        <option value="bb">10K Yellow Gold</option>
    </select>
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-menu-arrow" style="width: 98%;">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" title="14K White Gold">
        <span class="filter-option pull-left">14K White Gold</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu open">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu">
                <li data-original-index="0">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="10K Rose Gold"><span class="text">10K Rose Gold</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="1">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="10K White Gold"><span class="text">10K White Gold</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="metal_type" name="metal_type" value="14KW">
</div>
```

How to do with selenium using c#. I have tried using xpath but it throws the error.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='prod-value']/div/div/ul/li[0]/a")).Click();
```

Above code not able to find the exact path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> **//*[contains(@class,'prod-value')]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a**

There were two issues with that xpath.

- `prod-value` is not the only class present in first div
- Element indexes are 1-based, so there's no li[0]

Answer (score 1):

@derloopkat [provided with correct explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887293/selenium-get-element-by-xpath/49887405#49887405) (+1)

Another simple way to solve the issue is to use link text (in case there are no more `"10K Rose Gold"` links):

```
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("10K Rose Gold")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the dropdown to expand its option before you can choose any option.

```
// expand dropdown options
driver
  .FindElement(By.Css("div.prod-value button.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker"))
  .click();

// choose option
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("10K Rose Gold")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to expand the dropdown as  [Answered by Yong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49888716/4165839)

Then you need to click element by using xpath as [Answered by derloopkat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887405/4165839)

Here is final code for get final output:

```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.prod-value button.dropdown-toggle.selectpicker")).Click();
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'prod-value')]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")).Click();
```